# Calling all implementation of an interface within one call

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an interface and two implementations of that interface.
Now on the interface I am adding '@Component' annotation. One of the implementation has a '@primary' annotation which is only getting called up.
I want to call both the implementations when I call the interface's method from the autowired interface bean.

```
@Component
public interface CustomerPersister {
    AbuserDetails setAbuserDetails(AbuserDetails customer);
}


@Primary
@Component
public class CustomerRedisPersisterImpl implements CustomerPersister{
@Autowired
private CustomerManager customerManager;
@Override
public AbuserDetails setAbuserDetails(AbuserDetails customer) {
if(customerManager.setAbuserDetails
(customer,ATSNamespaces.ABUSERDETAILS)){
        return customer;
    }else{
        return new AbuserDetails();
    }
}



@Component
public class MongoDbRepositoryImpl implements CustomerPersister{
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Override
    public AbuserDetails setAbuserDetails(AbuserDetails customer) {
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("login").is(customer.getLogin()));
    System.out.println("query is:"+query);
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("isReturnAbuser", customer.getIsReturnAbuser());
    update.set("reasonReturnAbuser", customer.getReasonReturnAbuser());
    update.set("isCODThrottled", customer.getIsCODThrottled());
    update.set("reasonRTOAbuser", customer.getReasonRTOAbuser());
    update.set("isFakeEmail", customer.getIsFakeEmail());
    update.set("reasonFakeEmail", customer.getReasonFakeEmail());
    update.set("amount",customer.getAmount());
    WriteResult result = mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, AbuserDetails.class);
    System.out.println("This is the class that got returned:"+result.getClass());
    System.out.println("New design result:"+result);

    if(result!=null){
        if(result.getN() != 0)
            return customer; 
        else 
            return null;
    }else
        return null;
}





someOtherClass
    @Autowired
    private CustomerPersister customerPersister;


    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/abuser/details/set", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public AbuserDetails setAbuserDetails(@RequestBody AbuserDetails customer){
        return customerPersister.setAbuserDetails(customer);
    }
```

Comment: **1)**. *Which* method? you have declared 5. **2)**. Where do you implement the other 4 methods? **3)**. When do you want to call both implementing methods?

Comment: @Lino I just edited. Only one method is there. I have two implementation of that method. I want them both to get called. So later if I have a third implementation, I would be required to just add the implementation for that and make no change in the above code.
In someOtherClass I am calling the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Spring to autowire all implementations of an interface as a `List` and then call the method an all implementations.

```
class SomeClass {

    List<CustomerPersister> customerPersisters;

    @Autowired
    SomeClass(List<CustomerPersister> customerPersisters) {
        this.customerPersisters = customerPersisters;
    }

    public void setAbuserDetails(@RequestBody AbuserDetails customer) {
        for (CustomerPersister customerPersister: customerPersisters) {
            customerPersister.setAbuserDetails(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this will not allow you to return the result of `customerPersister.setAbuserDetails()`, because you can't return a single value from multiple persister calls. You either have to write some code in `SomeClass` that will determine which object should be returned or you could return a list of the results from all persisters. Or you have to redesign your interface to match the requirements.